# Gradual Wordpress to Laravel migration

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

We have a Wordpress website currently working and want to migrate to Laravel 5. For some reasons we want the website to be moved part-by-part. Every newly redesigned page will be implemented by Laravel and old pages still remain on Wordpress.

I want if there is a route registered for current URL in Laravel, then load it from Laravel, else let Wordpress to load it.

We don't want to have any `/wordpress/` in URL. Also the administrations panel should still be accessed using `/wp-admin` url without any prefix.

Is there any clear solution for this?

Comment: >.< Shoot whoever came up with that decision and then decide to build a new site in Laravel, adding any new pages just to that site, replacing WP in one go once the new site is ready.

Comment: I guess best thing would be to merge index.php files from WP and laravel, then create array with routes which pointing to redesign website(eg. ['/about', '/some-page']) and check in index.php which version You should use WP or laravel.

Comment: @BogdanKuštan I have used this solution right now. But It needs `/wordpress` prefix for `wp-admin` pages in URL

Comment: @Styphon Do I need a gun? lol

Comment: @Omid Sling shot is normally good enough. There's something satisfying about slinging a stone at someone stupid enough to suggest such a course of action.

Comment: @Styphon Anyway, why you think this is a stupid solution? just because it's making trouble?

Comment: @Omid Yea, you're just asking for trouble trying to keep both running. Projects like this always end up causing technical debt that will haunt you even after you stop using WP. You'll make compromises in your new site to keep it working with WP.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the solution exists. Recently, I managed to migrate my Wordpress site to Laravel "gradually". At first, I "combine" Laravel to use WP database using [Corcel](https://github.com/corcel/corcel) package. And the routes were still handled by WP, which Laravel just catch the full URL request and passed it to controller like this:

```
Route::get('/{ids}', 'UrlController@withIds')->where('ids', '^(?!admin).*');
```

where the `{ids}` was just passed to WP's `get_page_by_path($id);` function and returned the data to the blade template.